# xtic labels disappears (along x-axis) at the bottom of the graph

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot histogram using "gnuplot". The code I used is as blow:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

###PNG
set terminal pngcairo size 650,550 enhanced dash font "arial,10" #fontscale 1.20
set output "hb-maltoLyo12per.png"

set macro
labelFONT="font 'Arial,23'"
scaleFONT="font 'Arial,18'"
scaleFONT2="font 'Arial,13'"


set boxwidth 0.75 absolute
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set style histogram rowstacked
set style data histograms

set xtic  rotate by -30  1000 nomirror  @scaleFONT2 offset character -1, 0, 0
set ytics 100 nomirror  @scaleFONT
set mxtics 2
set mytics 5
set ytics 2
set yrange [0:10]
set ylabel "Hydrogen Bond"  @labelFONT
set xlabel ''                      

plot 'data_average_HB.dat' using 2 t "Inter-moleculear HB", '' using 3:xticlabels(1) t "Lipid to Solvent HB" with histogram
```

Using the above code, I get a plot as I shown [image: in histogram]

The xtics labels (along x-axis) go hide below the graph. Each one is long phrase. I want them to appear to visible.

Is there anything missing in my code? How I can achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot isn't very good at estimating the margins for special tic label formattings (e.g. long rotated labels). You can use `set bmargin` to set the bottom margin manually.

Try using

```
set bmargin 4
```

which would use a bottom margin corresponding to 4 character heights of the choosen font. You'll proably need to adjust the `4` in your case.